# Is there a way to enable minicom linewrap by default

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I use minicom when working on Cisco router serial terminals... by default, I use these settings in my [`~/.minirc.dfl`](https://github.com/mpenning/dotfiles/blob/master/.minirc.dfl):

```
pu port             /dev/ttyUSB0
pu baudrate         9600
pu bits             8
pu parity           N
pu stopbits         1
pu rtscts           No
pu xonxoff          No
pu minit
pu mreset
pu mhangup
```

What's interesting is that minicom defaults to *linewrap off*, and I haven't found a way to turn it on in `~/.minirc.dfl`.  When I've tried the obvious like:

```
pu linewrap         Yes
```

minicom barks that `**Line 9 of the personal config is unparsable`.

Other than a bash alias like `alias minicom="minicom -w"`, is there a way to default minicom to automatically wrap lines?  I would like to set this in `~/.minirc.dfl`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your guess should be correct, because this is exactly the line, minicom writes itself when invoked in *setup mode* via `minicom -s`:

```
# Machine-generated file - use "minicom -s" to change parameters.
pu linewrap         Yes
```

However it neither does not work on my machine. A workaround is to use the environment variable `MINICOM`

```
MINICOM="-w"
export MINICOM
```

as explained in the manual:

> When minicom starts, it first searches the MINICOM environment variable for command-line arguments (...)

Comment: I pulled `pu linewrap` after reading `src/rwconf.c`, so I just figured my understanding of C was broken.  I hadn't tried `-s`.  I'll file a bug.  It's odd that minicom doesn't even understand its own config format

Comment: The minicom maintainer asked me to post this comment (as he does not have enough reputation to do so):

The feature of setting a linewrapping value in the config file has only been added after version 2.6.1. So unfortunately this seems to be the expected behavior for this version.